# Is it right/possible to tag someone in comment while asking question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

While asking any question, if I know some one knows the answer from the community, is it right to tag him in comment to get attention and increase probability of getting right answer quickly.

It might flood that user with lots of notification, but it seems to be a better way to get attention from someone appropriate quickly. Is it right/possible?

As I know there is bounty option available for getting attention on question, but that can be used after 2 days, so this might be a better option.

Comment: The answer there includes a long overview of all the ways feature requests towards what you are asking have been rejected. That basically means: **No, it is not OK**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for quick reply, just wondering if it was possible. Anyway now its cleared :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to notify a user in a question. Also, **No, it is not ok** to try to get a specific user's attention to answer your question, even if they have already engaged with you in the comments to your question.

That sort of thing demonstrates **an extreme lack of respect** for someone else's time. If someone wants to answer your question, then they will, there is no need to spam and bother them with unsolicited, unwanted, and annoying messages begging them to answer your question.